# To Accept value from other control in same cshtml page in developing .Net MVC3 with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I think it must be answered already!

Something like :

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserDept)
```

Just the `UserDept` has few options, so I want to be get choices by users in radio or checkbox and this textbox can get the value, :)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually done with dropdown list, because there is a helper for it.

First, you have to populate data for that select list in your controller, like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ViewBag.PossibleMembers = memberRepository.All;
    return View(projectRepository.Find(id));
}
```

Then in your view, you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemberId, ((IEnumerable<RunDog2.Models.Member>)ViewBag.PossibleMembers).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
    Value = option.MemberId.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.MemberId == Model.MemberId)
}), "Choose...")
```

You can get this code generated with MvcScaffolding for example.

Comment: Thank Dampe! The textbox's value  for editing is from model, and can not be replaced. It only can be overwritted from other checkbox htmlhelper control.

Comment: I don't get that. But you of course don't have to use ViewBag, you can get that collection from model, if you have it available.